# QML update the property of Item inside the ListView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

```
Item {

Component.onComplete: {
    for (var i=0;i < 10;i++) {
        myModel.append({"myTxt": "SomeThing"+i});
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: myModel
}

ListView {
    id: listView
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    model: myModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        property string propItemState: 0;
        
        MyListItem {
            id: test
            itemText: myText
            itemState: propItemState;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to update the `propItemState` once the list is displayed.
For that, I have tried the below method but am getting an `undefined` error.
I am calling this method once the list model is updated.

```
function updateListItems() {
    for (var index=0;index < listView.count;index++) {
        console.log("propItemState: "+listView.contentItem.children[index].propItemState);
        listView.contentItem.children[index].propItemState = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#delegate-prop : "Delegates are instantiated as needed and may be destroyed at any time. [...] State should never be stored in a delegate."
Store the state outside your delegates, in your model or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `propItemState` to something outside of your delegate. Or you can add signal handler ([Connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html)), which listens to your model (for example; or to some another class) and changes state when your conditions met.

Example:

```
Item {
    Component.onComplete: {
        for (var i=0;i < 10;i++) {
            myModel.append({"myTxt": "SomeThing"+i});
        }

        internal.state = "1";
    }

    ListModel {
        id: myModel
    }

    QtObject {
        id: internal
        property string state: "0"
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        model: myModel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            property string propItemState: internal.state

            MyListItem {
                id: test
                itemText: myText
                itemState: propItemState;
            }
        }
    }
}
```